# Ошибка в выводе данных в шаблон ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs

Есть коллекция `sights`, в нее вложена коллекция `sight`, которое имеет поле `titleSight`. Проблема с выводом значения `titleSight` в шаблон. Выдает ошибку: `Cannot read property 'titleSight' of undefined`. Как правильно вывести значение поле `titleSight`?

**route.js**

```
 app.get('/sight-overall/:id', function (req, res) {
    Promise.all([
        Photo.find({}),
        Sight.find({_id: req.params.id})
    ]).then(function (data) {
        console.log('data:', data);
        res.render('sight-overall.ejs', {photoList: data[0], sights: data[1], isAuth: req.isAuthenticated()});
    });
```

**sights-overall.ejs**

```
 <% var sights = JSON.stringify(sights) %>
 <% if (locals.sights) { %>
   <div class="sight-overall__header">
        <h2><%= sights.sight.titleSight%></h2>
   </div>
 <% } %>
```

содержимое `data`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

содержимое бд:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `<% var sights = JSON.stringify(sights) %>` , сделайте такую переменную в ejs, и работайте с ней.

Comment: @uber42, а в чем у меня ошибка не видите? Просто аналогично делала для других моделей. проблем не было

Comment: вам хоть помогло ?

Comment: @uber42, выводит ту же самую ошибку. подправила пост, может не так вас поняла?

Comment: а зачем вы дважды в шаблон `data[0]` передаете ?

Comment: покажите что у вас выводит `console.log(data[0].sight)`

Comment: @uber42, опечатка. исправила. вывела data[1].sight, выводит undefined. В посте добавила скрин БД

Comment: `console.log(data[0][0].sight)` что дает ? Просто у вас почему-то массив обернут в массив.

Comment: @uber42, `console.log(data[1][0].sight)` выводит `{ titleSight: 'Ленин', descSight: '' }`

Comment: Ну вот и работайте с ним, в чем проблема, у вас в ejs переменная sights это массив, а вы не указывая индекс элемента расшариваете свойство sight

Comment: @uber42, вы не могли бы подсказать, как правильно обратиться к свойству titleSight. запуталась уже с этими индексами

Comment: `<%= sights[0].sight.titleSight%>` добавьте индекс

Answer (score 2):

Шаблонизатор пытается создать строку из вашего объекта, поэтому вы получаете такой результат.

---

Возьмем, например, такой объект:

```
sights = {
    sight : {
      title : "title"
    }
}
```

И передадим в наш шаблон:

```
res.render('index', { data: sights });
```

Наш объект встает на свое место в ejs в виде строки поэтому мы получаем подобный результат: `[object Object]` при `<%= data %>`.

Но если во время шаблонизации мы обернем строку `data` (которая изначально была объектом) в JSON.stringify, то наша строка обратно станет объектом.
Таким образом мы получим: `{"sight":{"title":"title"}}` при `<%= JSON.stringify(data) %>`